# Difference between Java and httpclient implementation of HTTP sampler in JMeter while uploading file

Tags: apache, http, jvm, jmeter

When I use Java implementation in HTTP sampler while recording script I'm able to upload file but I was not able to do the same when I use httpclient.

When I referred JMeter manual, it shows that Java implementation uses http from JVM for implementation, but I don't understand the difference here.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPClient sampler , refers to Apache http request implementation, while
Java sampler refers to Java http request implementation.
See [JMeter HTTP request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)